# Converting Generic List of object to defined collection class with Lambda and C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

This is an issue I have seen in two different jobs that use a 3-tier structure and haven't found a clean way around it.  This also applies to using LINQ statements I believe.

I have 2 classes, one is an object and the other is a defined collection of those objects that might have some additional functionality in it:

```
    public class TestObject
    {
       public Int32 id     {get; set;}
       public string value {get; set;}
    }

    public class TestObjectCollection: List<TestObject>
    {
       public TestObject Get(Int32 id)
       {
          return this.FirstOrDefault(item => item.id==id);
       }
    }
```

Say I use a lambda expression like:

```
    List<TestObject> result = data.Where(item => item.id > 0).ToList();
```

Is there an easy way to convert that list of objects to my defined collection without doing something like this:

```
    TestObjectCollection resultAsCollection = new TestObjectCollection()
    resultAsCollection.AddRange(result);
```

It seems like there should be a way to cast my GenericList returned by the Lambda expression to my TestObjectCollection without the added step looping through my returned results.

Comment: I can't see the problem with using a `List<T>`, or `EnhancedList<T>`, or `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`. `AddRange` typically accepts an IEnumerable<T> , which means you can pass the LINQ query directly. The problem is more likely in the implementation of `TestObjectCollection`

Comment: You want to replace the `.ToList()` call with a different extension method that creates your desired list type.

Comment: Maybe you should write an extension method to `DBSet` or `List`.

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't. `ToList` creates a `List<T>` - and there's no way of casting a plain `List<T>` to a `TestObjectCollection` without creating a new `TestObjectCollection`.

Personally I'd avoid creating a collection deriving from `List<T>` at all (I'd almost *always* use composition instead) but if you *really* want to have that collection, the simplest approach is to create your own extension method:

```
public static class TestEnumerable
{
     public static TestObjectCollection ToTestObjectCollection(this IEnumerable<TestObject> source)
     {
         return new TestObjectCollection(source);
     }
}
```

... and implement the appropriate constructor, of course, which can probably just chain to the `List(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor. Then you can write:

```
var resultAsCollection = data.Where(item => item.id > 0).ToTestObjectCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like there should be a way to cast my GenericList returned by
>   the Lamda expression to my TestObjectCollection without the added step
>   looping through my returned results

There isn't because with generic collections you can use covariance and not contravariance.

Other than Jon's solution (which is good) you can create constructor overload:

```
  public class TestObjectCollection: List<TestObject>
  {
     public TestObjectCollection(IEnumerable<TestObject> list) { AddRange(list);}
     ...
  }
```

Usage:

```
var resultAsCollection = new TestObjectCollection(data.Where(item => item.id > 0));
```